# Stripe One Time Payment + Recurring Payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I checked stripe api doc, but can not find the solution for (product_price + monthly_fee) model.
I can see Stripe::Charge.create is for one time payment and subscription is for recurring payment.
Guide link or Sample code would be very thankful.
I tried with below code, but no success yet.

```
def save_and_pay(params)
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => subscription.user.email,
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )
  subscription.user.update(gateway_customer_id: customer.id, is_active: true)
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => (subscription.plan_price * 100).to_i,
    :currency    => 'usd',
    :description => 'subscription Payment'
  )
  self.payment_status = charge.paid
  self.payment_response = charge.status
  self.save    
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand: what is the problem to create 2 charges using the existing tools - a standard one time and a subscription?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We need to see your attempt to solve it with the minimum code necessary to reproduce the problem. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: Hi Tin Man, Thanks for your guide. I checked Stripe API doc and wrote my code like above, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

1) You need to create a plan in stripe dashboard. (For this code I created a plan with monthly_fee)

2) You can add below code to your file

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :email => "user@user.user",
  :source  => params[:stripeToken]
)

invoiceItem = Stripe::InvoiceItem.create({
  :customer    => customer.id,
  :amount      => 100,
  :currency    => 'usd',
  :description => 'subscription Payment'
})

charge = Stripe::Subscription.create(
  :customer => customer,
  :items => [
    {
      :plan => "monthly_fee",
      :quantity => 5
    },
  ]
)
```

Hope this help the others who face the same case.
Thanks